# CSS styling with premade template.

Tags: html, css, position

So, I downloaded a free website template. I modified the layout a little and now I'm having problems getting the top location icons to become smaller and position themselves all in one straight line. I've tried changing the "image image-full" tag in the CSS file from 100% to a smaller percentage. That makes the icon smaller but then the icons won't position themselves to be all on one line. The site is found at http://harmlesscrack.com/br/. I've torn apart this CSS file changing everything I can find that links to the location icons and just about given up on all hope of understanding how they formatted this CSS.

P.S. Please don't flag this for "not being a useful question.' I really do need help here.

Answer (score 0):

Just explicitly set the widths of the `<div class="4u">`, or alter the `.\34 u` class.  For example, the following will place the 4 containers in-a-row spanning only one line:

```
// HTML markup
<div class="4u">
    ...
</div>

// CSS
.\34 u {
    width: 24.333333%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've updated my original post to include a screenshot of the result. Perhaps you have an overriding style?  Without seeing your actual implementation, and with the little info you've given, it's hard to tell.